# Focusing on window in AutoIT by class

Tags: autoit

I would like to focus on window of class 32770 so I use:

```
ControlFocus("[CLASS:#32770]","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("[CLASS:#32770]","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("[CLASS:#32770]","","Button1")
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Try `"[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]"` instead of `"Edit1"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to make this script workable on different language versions of Windows, that's why, instead of using explicit title, I tried to use class. Final solution was to use @MUILang.